# Azure Linux App Service MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: azure-web-app-service

We need to increase the MaxRequestWorkers on an Azure Linux App Service with a PHP app (Moodle) from the default of 256.  The ServerLimit shows as 1000 in phpinfo.php, and the MaxRequestWorkers remain at 256.

We have used the App Service startup command to overwrite the values in
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf and
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf,
but it has no effect.

We have also inserted MaxRequestLimit 512 in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf, but still no effect.

I would like to know if it is possible to increase MaxRequestWorkers in this environment?

Answer (score 1):

I think `root access` is provided but it looks like changes made are not kept.  The default PHP image for App Service uses Apache, and it doesn't let you customize the site root for your app.

If you want the `mpm_prefork.conf` file configuration to take effect, it is recommended to use custom Docker image instead-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?pivots=container-linux

**Reference post:**

[1. Microsoft Azure Web App - How to update apache vhost config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985799/microsoft-azure-web-app-how-to-update-apache-vhost-config)

[2. Change httpd.conf on Web App on Linux](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0850341c-44c9-4623-bb02-ad89b18794f1/change-httpdconf-on-web-app-on-linux?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)